# Can't open Ubuntu from Chromebook

Tags: 14.04, xfce, chromebook, chroot

I use Ubuntu XFCE4 and I just upgraded to 14.04. So I rebooted my computer like it asked and when I tried to boot into Ubuntu, it came up with the usual message about an error and that it closed unsuccessfully (sorry I can't show you the actual message because my copy and paste doesn't work in the shell). Then I try to reload Ubuntu with

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n precise -u
```

but then I got:

```
Downloading latest crouton installer...
##################################################################### 100.0%
/usr/local/chroots/precise does not exist: cannot update.
Valid chroots:
elementary
```

Could someone help me get Ubuntu back?

Answer (score 0):

`usr/local/chroots/precise does not exist; cannot update.`

This means there is no chroot called "precise".

when you do a distribution upgrade, the name of the chroot changes. Since you went from precise to trusty, you need to update crouton so that it knows there's a newly named chroot:

Code:`sudo -e ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n elementary`

Comment: could you tell me how to update crouton please?

Comment: just copy and paste the code in your terminal

Comment: I tryed the code but it just says "sudo: /usr/libexec/editor: command not found"

Comment: do you have any text editor ?

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n trusty` paste it to the terminal and let me know what's happen

Comment: it came up with the same message as above the trusty does not exist

Comment: nevermind i figured it out all i had to do was replace trusty with elementary

Comment: okay I edit the post. Check if everything is okay or not. That was my mistake . I did not notice properly the  output. and If it's solve your problem "mark as accept". Thanks

Comment: On my install it was required that I include sh after sudo as stated on the crouton page. Without including sh updating did not work for me. https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#a-new-version-of-crouton-came-out-my-chroot-is-therefore-obsolete-and-sad